# Using Segue, How do I control the visibility of a view in a different view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have two view controllers that are linked via segue. One view controller (`ViewController2`) has multiple views within it which responds to the `pageIndex` in the first view controller(`ViewController1`). So what I'm trying to achieve is that `onClick` if `pageIndex == 0` on the `ViewController1`,  one of the views should become visible. I have done this multiple times with `Labels` and `ImageViews` but when it comes to making a view visible I can't seem to achieve it. So I need help to achieve it.

ViewController1:

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segueIdentifier(for: segue) == .reveal,
      let secondViewController = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {

      if pageIndex == 0 {
        //secondViewController.viewabc.isHidden = false

      }else if pageIndex == 1{
        //secondViewController.viewdef.isHidden = false

      }else{
        //secondViewController.viewghi.isHidden = false

      }


      secondViewController.transitioningDelegate = self

      }

  }

  @IBAction func handleTap() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: .reveal, sender: self)


  }
}

extension ViewController1: SegueHandlerType {
  enum SegueIdentifier: String {
    case reveal
  }
}
```

ViewController2:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var viewabc: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var viewdef: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var viewghi: UIView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


      }
```

In the storyboard all 3 views are set to hidden

Comment: Why you don't use UITabbarController? It is a good solution for your problem.

Comment: @EkremDuvarbasi I have used UITabBarController before but for this it doesn't fulfil the design I'm trying to achieve. The full code for this creates an animation of a card being flipped when it is clicked to show the view in the ViewController2. The entire animation works well but I'm having issues in showing the views when the card has been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the pageIndex value from ViewController1 to ViewController2.

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segueIdentifier(for: segue) == .reveal,
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
            secondViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
            secondViewController.pageIndex = pageIndex
        }
    }
}
```

And update ViewController2 views based on the pageIndex value

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    var pageIndex: Int?
    @IBOutlet weak var viewabc: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewdef: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewghi: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if pageIndex == 0 {
            self.viewabc.isHidden = false
        }else if pageIndex == 1{
            self.viewdef.isHidden = false
        }else{
            self.viewghi.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```